# Geofire-js: Return all key's whose instantaneous location matches geoQuery

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I’m working with Firebase on a project, and I’m having trouble wrapping my head around how the querying works. I’m trying to query and find any other user’s that are within a certain radius of the current user’s location.

I’m able to create the the geoQuery, but I’m not sure how to return the user's whose locations are within the radius.

From the examples, it seems that `key_entered` is only triggered when a location in the DB changes. All my location’s are all static once set, so I just want to do a query, then return all the user’s whose instantaneous location falls within the queries radius.

Is this possible with Geofire?

My location information is saved in Firebase like this:

```
users {
   uid: {
        location: {
          g: 'GeoHash',
          l: [lat, long]
         }
      }
   }
```

Here's my Query:

```
let geoQuery = geoFire.query({
                center: [currentUser.location.l[0], currentUser.location.l[1]],
                radius: 1000
            });
```

Comment: The `key_entered` is actually triggered even if a location is just a static value and has not changed. Similar to how Firebase's `value` event will fire once with the initial value, `key_entered` will fire for every value which matches your `GeoQuery`, even if the `GeoQuery` was created after that value was last changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I hadn't be storing the locations using geoFire's `set` method, so the geoHash was never created, giving geoFire nothing to query off of. Thanks for the help @jacob!

Comment: Is it possible in Javascript?  To search keys (list of keys) of near by static(fixed) locations - which are pre-added in firebase datastore.

Note: not using 'key_entered' because 'key_entered' only fires when new or position updated. What about previously added locations but coming under given radius.

How is it possible??

Comment: @AnkitMaheshwari Did you find the solution ?

Comment: @YoloYolo Not yet!